# postfix::header_checks custom multi-line text replace in the mail header

Tags: postfix

I very successfully dealt with single line headers in `pcre:/etc/postfix/header_check`. But when it comes to multi-lines, I'm a bit frustrated. Here is a part of header:

```
X-MS-Has-Attach:
X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
    boundary="_000_8FA6C259529CB0418FBDF96A6B22A486209F15MAILmynetworkloca_"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--_000_8FA6C259529CB0418FBDF96A6B22A486209F15MAILmynetworkloca_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

test

--_000_8FA6C259529CB0418FBDF96A6B22A486209F15MAILmynetworkloca_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

And what I need, just to get rid of strings like

```
--_000_8FA6C259529CB0418FBDF96A6B22A486209F15MAILmynetworkloca_
```

Or at least replace last part `MAILmynetworkloca_` to something like `maildomaincom_`
I've tried to put to my `/etc/postfix/header_check`

```
/MAILmynetworkloca_/ REPLACE maildomaincom_
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Boundary parts isn't *visible* directly to user. It's only used by mail client to mark attachment boundary. Why do you want to replace it?

Comment: @masegaloeh All my users use the same exchange server, but different domains. So all their emails should not contain anything in common even in mail headers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI: The line `--__INSERTSOMERANDOCHARHERE000MAILmynetwok` isn't part of email headers. And maybe you don't wanna to alter/remove it.

Anyway, here to do it.

You should use both `header_checks` and `body_checks` to replace those line.

Content of `main.cf`

```
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/mimereplace
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/mimereplace
```

Content of `/etc/postfix/mimereplace`

```
/^(.*)MAILmynetworkloca_(.*)/ REPLACE ${1}maildomaincom_${2}
```

Comment: `bad REPLACE header text "boundary="_000_E6E9F66E17B7214FBDC69E9F8F4DDE8D33EF94maildomaincom_" in mime_header_checks map -- need "headername: headervalue"`. But I dont know the header name?

Comment: yes, this worked for me! thank you. All were replaced. But the weird thing now - gmail doesnt want to show message body as html anymore? Why is that?

Comment: i figured out the HTML problems. Header replace somehow is removing last '"' from boundary. so in header_checks it should be like `....REPLACE ${1}maildomaincom_"` with " at the end

Comment: i've made some changes for your answer. this is fully working version. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to use something like `/MAILmynetworkloca_$/m REPLACE maildomaincom_` .

The dollar sign means at the end of the string, the  `m` should put it in multiline mode (according to the [PCRE](http://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) pages)

Why you'd want to replace that header I don't know, but it's your mail server :)